# I try to ask user for input and then print it out, but it does not print

Tags: java

I want it to print: "Your score is first", but it won't.

I'm using the `toString()` and I am completely a beginner in Java. If anybody have any idea, please tell me.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int i)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = i;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {

        return name + " : " + age;
    }

    /*
    **  Implement the natural order for this class
    */
    public int compareTo(Person p)
    {
        return getName().compareTo(p.getName());
    }

    static class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person>
    {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
        {
            int age1 = p1.getAge();
            int age2 = p2.getAge();

            if (age1 == age2)
                return 0;
            else if (age1 > age2)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pie;
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ass;
        pie = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your Score is  " + pie);
        ass = input1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + ass);

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add( new Person("Homer", 1) );
        people.add( new Person("Marge", 35) );
        people.add( new Person("Bart", 15) );
        people.add( new Person(ass, pie) );

        // Sort by natural order

        Collections.sort(people);
        System.out.println("Sort by Natural order");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        // Sort by reverse natural order

        Collections.sort(people, Collections.reverseOrder());
        System.out.println("Sort by reverse natural order");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        //  Use a Comparator to sort by age

        Collections.sort(people, new Person.AgeComparator());
        System.out.println("Sort using Age Comparator");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        //  Use a Comparator to sort by descending age

        Collections.sort(people,
            Collections.reverseOrder(new Person.AgeComparator()));
        System.out.println("Sort using Reverse Age Comparator");
        System.out.println("\t" + people);
    }
}
```

What I expect is:
It print "Your Score is:" first
and the I can enter the information I want.

Comment: what do you get when you print person? What exactly do you want to do? could you please be clearer?

Comment: If your program does not behave as expected: What does it instead?

Comment: You can use only a Scanner "for all".

Comment: @MiguelAngel_LV Although it is unusual, unnecessary, and misleading, using two scanners is still allowed and technically no problem.

Comment: Please provide the output of your code and Expected result.

Comment: Hmmm ... Additionally, I simply tried your code and it works very well. Please update your question with a detailed problem description. Voting to close.

Comment: `pie` and `ass` are not good names for variables.  Consider changing them to `score` and `name` so the names are actually meaningful.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It seems he/she expect to print the score and the name after get both inputs.  According to current implementation once you type and press enter it will print the result without waiting for the next input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are pressing the enter after you input the Score,  you should read the 'nextLine' to wait for the next input.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pie = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        String ass = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Your Score is  " + pie);
        System.out.println("Your name is " + ass);
```

Note: It is better to close the Scanner after read the stream.

Answer (score -1):

```
I want it to print: "Your score is first", but it won't.
```

It is not printing first because you are asking the `scanner` for **input** before you print the message

**solution:**

```
        System.out.println("Your Score is  " + pie);
        pie = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + ass);
        ass = input1.nextLine();
```

Comment: Now you are printing first and then asking for a value!? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose what he actually saying is '"Your score is" first'

Comment: Might be. But what would be the intention for first printing the sentence and then asking for input? I do not think, that he wanted it this way. It makes much more sense to understand his question as this: "I try to ask user for input and then print it out, but it does not print". But as this is only speculative, we should ask the OP to update his question or vote to close. I don't think that this answer will be of any help.